# VBA in Outlook is not being applied

Tags: vba, outlook

I'm suddenly in the position of maintaining a form in Outlook that helps users submit requests properly.  Here's the how that goes:

1. Open the form
2. Fill in the form
3. Remove cruft, like signatures, etc
4. Click "Send"

At this point, a VBA script (Project1 -> Microsoft Outlook Objects -> ThisOutlookSession) should kick in and do a couple of things:

1. Ask the user if they want to send.
2. If so, turn their entries on the form into a JSON body suitable for the receiving system and send the email.

It appears that the VBA script is not being called at all.  So, a couple of questions:

1. What conditions determine if the VBA script is called?  Is it simply the name, "ThisOutlookSession"?
2. Is there some very basic thing that I can replace the script with temporarily that makes it very obvious?  I'm thinking along the lines of what I do in Python when I'm not sure a condition is being met, so I add something like `print('This function was called')`
3. Any other suggestions?

As you can tell, I'm very new to this, so small words are appreciated, and thank you.

Answer (score 0):

I think that you can start from this point with the [Application.ItemSend event](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/outlook.application.itemsend), that called when user clicks the send button:

```
' in ThisOutlookSession module
Private Sub Application_ItemSend(ByVal Item As Object, Cancel As Boolean)
    If Item.Class = olMail Then
        If MsgBox("Are you want to send the letter '" & Item.Subject & "'?", vbYesNo) = vbNo Then
            Cancel = True 'don't send the original letter
        Else
            ' process the letter as you want
            Cancel = True 'debug
        End If
    End If
End Sub
```

The command in VBA like `print("smth")` in Python is `Debug.Print "smth"` that prints text in Immediate window in VBE